# Access denied when executing a command via subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, subprocess, libreoffice

I want to use LibreOffice to convert a file to pdf. I can do it alright from the command line, but I haven't been able to make the call from python. I'm on a Mac and there are two steps:

1. Go to the libreoffice's folder (usually at `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS`)
2. Execute `./soffice --headless --convert-to pdf input_folder--outdir output_folder`

I tried

```py
subprocess.run(["cd", libreoffice_path])  
subprocess.run(["./","soffice","--headless","--convert-to", "pdf", input_folder, "--outdir", output_folder])
```

but I'm getting a `Permission denied: './'` error.

I thought it was an access error and made soffice executable (although I suspect it already was) by using `chmod +x` from the command line. Still no luck.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You split the first argument into two. Try running:

```
subprocess.run(["./soffice", "--headless", "--convert-to", "pdf", input_folder, "--outdir", output_folder])
```

also, a better way to change the working directory is to use `os.chdir`:

```
import os
os.chdir(libreoffice_path)
```

Comment: Another way to change directory when starting a subprocess is to use the `cwd` argument to `subprocess.run`: `subprocess.run([...], cwd=libreoffice_path, ...)`.

Comment: @larsks You're right, cwd is definitely the way to go as it keeps the code more compact.